# Finding the number of divisors that satisfy some condition - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-factorization

Let $N$ = $2^1$$^5%$$3^1$$^6$. How many divisors of $N^2$ less than $N$ are there which don't divide $N$

MY ATTEMPT:

We have:

$N^2$ = $2^3$$^0%$$3^3$$^2$. The number of divisors of $N^2$ which do divide N should be of the form:

$2^a$$3^b$, where $a$ is a factor of 15 and $b$ a factor of 16

so, $a$ = 0, 3, 5, 15

$b$ = 0, 2, 4, 8, 16.

So, we have $5^4$ combinations.

The total number of divisors of $N^2$ are $1023$.

So, the total number which dont satisfy this condition:

$1023$ - $625$ = $398$, which is not the answer

The answer is somehow 240

Can someone help?

Comment: $2^a3^b \mid N $ if $a \le 15, b \le 16$.

Comment: Your description of the divisors of $N$ is incorrect. There is no need for $a$ to divide $15$, for instance.  I suggest that you work this out for smaller numbers. Try $n=2^43^2$, say.  In that case, everything is small enough for you to write it all out explicitly.